# Geometry, which figures are possible?

Tags: geometry

Which of the following situations are possible? The numbers are the length.

What do they really mean by "which figures are possible"? 
And what about the idea that you should show it?

[image]

Comment: For example: the last one is impossible, because of triangle inequality.

Comment: Hint:  apply [Ceva's Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/ceva.shtml)

Comment: At least one of the first two must be impossible, if you look closely.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

[image]

NOW YOU SHOULD BE ABLE TO DO THIS
this theorem is called Cevas theorem